# How to change size of y ticks when plotting them on right side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, font-size

Basically, I plot the y axis on the right side of my figure and I would like to set the fontsize of these ticks.

So here an example where I switch the y-axis on right and set the fontsize but when I display the figure, the fontsize didn't changed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.yaxis.tick_right()#same result with ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].label.set_fontsize(50)
plt.show()
```

As you can see if you run this code, the 0.0 ticks on y-axis is at the same size than the others (ie. 12, the default one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two labels for each tick. The right-hand-side label is the `label2`. Hence,

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].label2.set_fontsize(50)
```

would give the desired output here.
However, you might rather want to set the fontsize for both labels simultaneously, instead of digging in the object tree, i.e.

```
ax.get_yticklabels()[0].set_fontsize(50)
```

Comment: Thank's ! Didn't know that a label2 existed !

Thank's again.